# how to change the Folder structure under TFS Source Control

Tags: tfs

I need to change the branching of folder under TFS Source Control for my project
is it possible?

Right now my project is under AAA folder.

Now I need to keep it in AAA---> DEV--> My project...

Answer (score 5):

Sure.  Just do it via Source Control Explorer.  Right click the folder and select move.  Note that you can't do it for top level folders since they are tied to the project name.

If you want to do it via the command line you'd be looking for the "tf.exe rename" command